# Connection pooling in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database, ado.net

I´ve been looking for it yet in stackoverflow without success...

Is it posible a connection pooling in asp.net? Is it worthwhile? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually really simple, simply add the following parameters to your connection string and (either in code or in the web.config) and ASP.NET will pick up the rest:

```
Min Pool Size=5; Max Pool Size=60; Connect Timeout=300;
```

*Note: The Connection Timeout is in seconds and is not required.*

Answer (score 1):

by default max pool is 100